# Ubuntu cron job mysql warning not to use password in command line, how to fix?

Tags: mysql, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I am using a cron job to reset my database and each time the cron runs the line-

```
mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD -h localhost DBNAME < /var/www/SITEFOLDER/mysqldumpfile.sql
```

Ubuntu warns me not to use the password in the command line. How can I use the reset cron command without using the password in a text format and causing any security issues?

Comment: You could write a bash script, and call that instead, or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/399262/connect-to-mysql-trough-command-line-without-need-root-password) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store user & password in a file, and give the path to that file when you use a mysql client.

```
mysql --defaults-file /path/to/some/file.cnf DBNAME < /var/www/SITEFOLDER/mysqldumpfile.sql
```

In the .cnf file, you can list user, password, host, and other connection parameters.

```
[client]
user = scott
password = tiger
host = localhost
```

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-file-options.html